# Migrate DTS Jobs to 2008 Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, ssis

We have been running SQL Server 2000 for years.

Finally, at long last, we have an SQL 2008 Server being shipped in.

We have many DTS jobs on our SQL 2000 Server that need to be migrated to the SQL 2008 Server.

Where can I go to look up how to convert DTS jobs so that they can be run on SQL 2008?

I am a WinForms C# developer that makes calls, builds stored procedures and occasionally creates a new table for our SQL Server, but I am not a Database or Network Administrator by title.

I want to make sure I do this right so that our company has minimal down time.

From our Network Administrator:

> From what I am reading, I will have to do more research, we have to convert all the Data Transformation Services (DTS) packages to SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). I do not know what this may take but from my understanding, the jobs are written in .Net. If we could migrate them, great, but if not we may have to write new ones for all, which would not be that hard once you have the first one written.

Does this help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can import the old DTS packages into SQL Server 2008 using the DTS Migration Wizard. You can find it on the SQL 2008 Management Studio at the following folder: **Server -> Management -> Legacy -> Data Transformation Services - Migration Wizard**. Point to the current source of the packages and this should help you do your job.

You should be able to find more information here: [Support for SQL 2000 DTS packages in SQL 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500440.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: [+1] That could be exactly what I need. I'll mark this as the answer, if so. Thanks!